# Protect a directory via .htaccess which is located out of main directory

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess

I am serving a documantation database and link a directory-listing which are located outside of the main directory. Like:

```
Apache main directory: /var/www/
Files: /scratch/files/
```

I added the "/scratch/files" in the conf as a directory and in order to view the directories as built-in directory listing. Now I want to protect the parent folders in directory-listing by adding .htaccess files into the linked directory.

This doesn't work because "/scratch/files" is not located in "/var/www".

What would be the easiest/best solution to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Location directives should still work fine, since they will even work on things that have no relation to the document root (eg. reverse proxy or redirect entries)...

Comment: Location directives work if they defined in the main apache configuration file. But .htaccess files cannot be read in these directories.

Comment: Location is meant for resources that are not part of the file system. For just showing files resident on a different part of the file system from the rest of the content, using Directory is the most common way to go about it.

Comment: I admit to have read "htaccess like protection" into "via .htaccess" ... the usual mod_auth directives (including using a .htpasswd file) will work in Locations.

Answer (score 0):

In the `<Directory>` directive for /var/www , there is usually some directive called `AllowOverride`. This is what allows you to set limits in .htaccess in that directory tree. If you want to be able to use .htaccess in /scratch/files, you need to enter the same `AllowOverride` for that directory.

If you need further help, please post the relevant parts of your config file.